# how to check Circle latitude longitude

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have following query how to check latitude and longitude are in circle or not but its show wrong result please help

```
 declare @latitudeCar float = 25.681137335685306;  
declare @longitudeCar float = 66.697998046875;
declare @latitudePlace float = 25.918526162075153;
declare @longitudePlace float = 66.170654296875;


declare @source geography = 'POINT(' + cast(@latitudeCar as nvarchar) + ' ' + cast(@longitudeCar as nvarchar) + ')'
declare @target geography = 'POINT(' + cast(@latitudePlace as nvarchar) + ' ' + cast(@longitudePlace as nvarchar) + ')'
declare @radius float = 164096.68447201277
declare @check float
declare @isPastCircle bit

set @check = (select @source.STDistance(@target)/1609.344)
--select @source.STDistance(@target)/1000

set @isPastCircle = (select case when @check > @radius then 1 else 0 end);
select @isPastCircle [isPastCircle], @check [carDistance], @radius [acceptableRadius]
```

Always result is Wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do your calculations in some fixed radius specified in miles but you're tripping the conversions. Below is a cleaned up version of the code:

```
declare @latitudeCar float = 25.681137335685306, 
    @longitudeCar float = 66.697998046875,
    @latitudePlace float = 25.918526162075153,
    @longitudePlace float = 66.170654296875;


declare @source geography = geography::Point(@latitudeCar, @longitudeCar, 4326),
    @target geography = geography::Point(@latitudePlace, @longitudePlace, 4326);

declare @radius_in_miles int = 100;

declare @radius_in_meters float = @radius_in_miles * 1609.344;

select @target.STBuffer(@radius_in_meters).STContains(@source) AS [isWithinCircle],
   @target.STDistance(@source) AS [distance_in_meters],
   @target.STBuffer(@radius_in_meters).STDisjoint(@source) AS [isPastCircle];
```

TL;DR - Try, as often as possible, to abstract your conversions away. In this case, I'm specifying my desired radius in the units I'm used to (i.e. miles) and then using a *different variable* to hold the desired radius that the spatial reference uses (if you're ever in doubt, just query `sys.spatial_reference_systems`). Also note that I simplified the within/outside of specified radius calculations to use `STContains()` and `STDisjoint()` (respectively). I'm assuming that you don't actually care about the distance between the two points, so using those alone should speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems correct other than the "<" in the select case. It should be:

```
set @isPastCircle = (select case when @check > @radius then 1 else 0 end);
```

Comment: result is false :(

Comment: I just ran the latest version of the code you posted. IsPastCircle is not always false. Set latitudeCar = 0, longitudeCar = 0, and radius = 10

Comment: Can you be more specific? How exactly is the result wrong?

Comment: my car latitude and longitude are in Circle but its show 0 its false

Comment: If your car latitude and longitude are in the Circle, then isPastCircle should be 0.

Comment: If your car latitude and longitude are outside of the Circle, then isPastCircle should be 1.

Comment: In other words, if your CarDistance is greater than acceptable radius, then isPastCircle should be 1.

Comment: i entered 28.92163128242129;   67.840576171875; its show 0 :( this lat long are outside the circle

Comment: What is your radius?

Comment: 164096.68447201277

Comment: The car distance is 141; whereas, the acceptable radius is 164096. Since 141 < 164096, the car is inside of the circle. Therefore, isPastCircle should be 0